# Filter dataframe by value only if the value is not a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to filter a dataframe by values received in JSON like below:

```
region = request_json['region_value']
ma = request_json['ma_value']
market = request_json['market_value']
subsegment = request_json['subsegment_value']

filtered =df[
    (df['Region'] == region) &
    (df['MA/Segment'] == ma) &
    (df['Market'] == market) &
    (df['Subsegment'] == subsegment)
]
```

However, if `region`, `ma`, `market` or `subsegment` equal `'All'`, I don't want to include it in the filtering.

So for example if `region` = `'All'`, the code should be like this:

```
filtered =df[
        (df['MA/Segment'] == ma) &
        (df['Market'] == market) &
        (df['Subsegment'] == subsegment)
    ]
```

I would like to avoid multiple ifs and go for a more elegant solution instead. I would welcome any ideas.

Comment: I think for your problem, you will need to use `logical_and.reduce` because one of your columns has a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.logical_and.reduce`; this will work even if your column names have spaces, special characters, etc:

```
conditions = {
    'Region': region, 'MA/Segment': ma, 'Market': market, 'Subsegment': subsegment}

mask = pd.np.logical_and.reduce([
    df[k] == v for k, v in conditions.items() if v != 'All'])
df[mask]
```

---

Another option is `query`, but this will work assuming your column names conform to valid python identifier names.

```
query = ' and '.join([
    f'{k}=={repr(v)}' for k, v in conditions.items() if v != 'All'])    
df.query(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do with `sum`

```
mask=((df['Region'] == region) +
      (df['MA/Segment'] == ma) +
      (df['Market'] == market) +
      (df['Subsegment'] == subsegment)).sum(axis=1).eq(3)

df=df[mask]
```